# @JsonIgnoreProperties and anything for controlling JSON doesn't work at Spring boot

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, jackson

I'm facing a circular reference problem when attempting to serialize my entities using Jackson and Hibernate. The application throws a StackOverflowError with the error message: "Infinite recursion."

I have a bidirectional relationship between the **Lesson**, **Student** and **Attendance** entities, where Attendance can have multiple students, and a lesson can have multiple attendance. The entities are mapped using JPA annotations, and I'm using Jackson for JSON serialization.

```
2023-05-28 19:39:09.548 DEBUG 15011 --- [nio-4800-exec-3] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2023-05-28 19:39:09.549 ERROR 15011 --- [nio-4800-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: java.util.HashSet[0]->com.example.demo.domains.users.Student["attendance"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet[0]->com.example.demo.domains.lessons.Attendance["lesson"]->com.example.demo.domains.lessons.PlainLesson["students"]->java.util.HashSet[0]->com.example.demo.domains.users.Student["attendance"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet[0]->com.example.demo.domains.lessons.Attendance["lesson"]->com.example.demo.domains.lessons.PlainLesson["students"]->java.util.HashSet[0]->com.example.demo.domains.users.Student["attendance"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet[0]->com.example.demo.domains.lessons.Attendance["lesson"]->com.example.demo.domains.lessons.PlainLesson["students"]->java.util.HashSet[0]->com.example.demo.domains.users.Student["attendance"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet[0]->com.example.demo.domains.lessons.Attendance["lesson"]->com.example.demo.domains.lessons.PlainLesson["students"]->java.util.HashSet[0]->com.example.demo.domains.users.Student["attendance"]-> ... 
->com.example.demo.domains.lessons.PlainLesson["students"])] with root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1013) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
```

I have tried various approaches to handle the circular reference issue, including using @JsonIgnore, @JsonIgnoreProperties, @JsonBackReference, @JsonManagedReference, @JsonIdentityInfo, and even custom serializers and deserializers. However, none of these solutions have resolved the problem.

I suspect that there might be other factors contributing to the issue, or I might be missing something in my code configuration. I would greatly appreciate any insights, suggestions, or alternative approaches to resolve this circular reference problem and enable successful serialization of my entities.

I can provide the relevant code snippets and the full stack trace of the exception if needed.

Here is code sources:
**Attendance**

```
import com.example.demo.BaseEntity;
import com.example.demo.domains.users.Student;
import javax.persistence.*;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import lombok.*;


@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Attendance extends BaseEntity {

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"attendance"})
    Lesson lesson;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"lessons", "authorities", "roles", "events", "coachings", "competitionMember", "attendance", "student"})
    Student student;

    @OneToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    CanceledLesson canceledLesson;

    Boolean didAttend;
}
```

**Lesson**

```
package com.example.demo.domains.lessons;

import com.example.demo.domains.users.Student;
import com.example.demo.domains.users.Teacher;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;
import javax.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Lesson {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    Long id;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "time", columnDefinition = "ENUM ('am0915', 'am1000', 'am1045', 'am1130', 'pm1205', 'pm0105', 'pm0150', 'pm0235', 'pm0320', 'pm0405', 'pm0450', 'pm0535', 'pm0620', 'pm0705', 'pm0750') not null", nullable = false)
    LessonTimes time;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    public LocalDate date;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"lessons", "roles", "authorities", "events"})
    Teacher teacher;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "lesson")
    @JsonManagedReference
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"lesson"}, ignoreUnknown = true)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Attendance> attendance;

    public Set<Student> getStudents() {
        return this.getAttendance().stream().map(Attendance::getStudent).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

    public void setStudents(Set<Student> studentSet) {
        var attendance = studentSet.stream().map(student -> Attendance.builder()
                .lesson(this)
                .student(student)
                .build()
        ).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        this.setAttendance(attendance);
    }
}
```

**Student**

```
package com.example.demo.domains.users;

import com.example.demo.domains.activities.coaching.Coaching;
import com.example.demo.domains.activities.competition.CompetitionMember;
import com.example.demo.domains.activities.event.Event;
import com.example.demo.domains.lessons.*;
import com.example.demo.security.user.JwtUser;
import com.example.demo.security.user.Position;
import com.example.demo.security.user.Role;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;
import javax.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"role", "canceledLessons", "authorities", "lessons", "events", "lessonCredits", "coachings", "competitionMember"}, allowGetters = true)
public class Student extends JwtUser {

    public Student(Long id) {
        super(id);
    }

    public Student(JwtUser jwtUser) {
        super(jwtUser);
    }

    {
        this.setRole(Set.of(Role.ROLE_USER));
        this.setPosition(Position.Student);
    }

    String phoneNumber;
    String telegram;
    String workAddress;
    String homeAddress;
    String danceLevel;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(updatable = false)
    Timestamp registered;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"student"})
    @JsonManagedReference
    Set<Attendance> attendance;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "student")
    private Set<NoteAboutStudent> noteAboutStudent;

    @ManyToMany
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"students"})
    @JoinTable(name = "students_coachings",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "coaching_id"))
    Set<Coaching> coachings;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"student"})
    Set<CompetitionMember> competitionMember;


    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "students_events",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "event_id"))
    Set<Event> events = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"student"})
    Set<LessonCredit> lessonCredits;

    public void addCompetition(CompetitionMember cm) {
        if (this.competitionMember == null) {
            this.competitionMember = new HashSet<>();
        }
        cm.setStudent(this);
        this.competitionMember.add(cm);
    }

    public Set<Lesson> getLessons() {
        return this.getAttendance().stream().map(Attendance::getLesson).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` at the same time which I don't see in your source code.

`@JsonManagedReference` - Using this , Jackson takes the forward part of the reference (e.g. your `Set<Attendance> attendance` in `Lesson` class), and converts it in a json-like storage format; this is the so-called marshalling process.

`@JsonBackReference` -  With this, Jackson looks for the back part of the reference (e.g. `Lesson lesson` in `Attendance` class) and leaves it as it is, not serializing it.

Try the below and it should work.

**Attendance**

```java
@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Attendance extends BaseEntity {

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonBackReference
    Lesson lesson;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonBackReference
    Student student;

    @OneToOne
    @JsonBackReference
    CanceledLesson canceledLesson;

    Boolean didAttend;
}
```

**Lesson**

```java
@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Lesson {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    Long id;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "time", columnDefinition = "ENUM ('am0915', 'am1000', 'am1045', 'am1130', 'pm1205', 'pm0105', 'pm0150', 'pm0235', 'pm0320', 'pm0405', 'pm0450', 'pm0535', 'pm0620', 'pm0705', 'pm0750') not null", nullable = false)
    LessonTimes time;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    public LocalDate date;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonBackReference
    Teacher teacher;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "lesson")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Attendance> attendance;

    public Set<Student> getStudents() {
        return this.getAttendance().stream().map(Attendance::getStudent).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

    public void setStudents(Set<Student> studentSet) {
        var attendance = studentSet.stream().map(student -> Attendance.builder()
                .lesson(this)
                .student(student)
                .build()
        ).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        this.setAttendance(attendance);
    }
}
```

**Student**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"role", "canceledLessons", "authorities", "lessons", "events", "lessonCredits", "coachings", "competitionMember"}, allowGetters = true)
public class Student extends JwtUser {

    public Student(Long id) {
        super(id);
    }

    public Student(JwtUser jwtUser) {
        super(jwtUser);
    }

    {
        this.setRole(Set.of(Role.ROLE_USER));
        this.setPosition(Position.Student);
    }

    String phoneNumber;
    String telegram;
    String workAddress;
    String homeAddress;
    String danceLevel;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(updatable = false)
    Timestamp registered;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    @JsonManagedReference
    Set<Attendance> attendance;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "student")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<NoteAboutStudent> noteAboutStudent;

    @ManyToMany
    @JsonManagedReference
    @JoinTable(name = "students_coachings",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "coaching_id"))
    Set<Coaching> coachings;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    @JsonManagedReference
    Set<CompetitionMember> competitionMember;


    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "students_events",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "event_id"))
    Set<Event> events = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    @JsonManagedReference
    Set<LessonCredit> lessonCredits;

    public void addCompetition(CompetitionMember cm) {
        if (this.competitionMember == null) {
            this.competitionMember = new HashSet<>();
        }
        cm.setStudent(this);
        this.competitionMember.add(cm);
    }

    public Set<Lesson> getLessons() {
        return this.getAttendance().stream().map(Attendance::getLesson).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
}
```